# Large test data file and github

Tags: git, testing, github, large-data

I am executing the test run in bamboo, using git as my repository. Now I need to run a test which checks upon a large data upload (where the file size is approx. 400MB. As the limit on github is 100MB, when I try to push this large file, the git push times out. Is there any other way I can execute my test from github, getting this file from any other location ? or is there a way to push this file to git?

Comment: Honestly you probably shouldn't even allow such a large file to be pushed to your Git repo.  I vote for just having a server side hook which checks for such large files and rejects them.

Comment: Another important thing to note is that, whenever you run these tests you'll be downloading a 400mb file that will be discarded. Even using a blob storage (which is what I'd recommend) this could greatly increase your costs. I'd suggest re-thinking your test suite so you don't need this 400mb file.

Comment: Github website says : GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB.  If you regularly push large files to GitHub, consider introducing Git Large File Storage (Git LFS) as part of your workflow. Git LFS works well with the GitHub Flow and can be used with any large file, regardless of its type. For more information, see "Versioning large files." https://help.github.com/en/articles/distributing-large-binaries

Answer (score 0):

It's better to generate such file before your test run.

In Windows you can use [`FileGen`](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/filegen/):

```
filegen test.txt 1024
```

will generate file `test.txt` with `1024` random symbols.

Or use this command in your bash:

```
head -c 5000 /dev/urandom >data.txt
```

This will generate data.txt file with 5000 random symbols.

For your case with 500Mb file it takes about 10 seconds to generate such file.